# How to put additional items into side menu from child view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I have a parent view used throughout my app:

```
$stateProvider
    .state("app", {
        abstract: true,
        url: "/app",
        templateUrl: "app/layout/menu-layout.html",
        controller: "MenuLayoutController as vm"
    })
```

It contains an `ion-nav-view` for the main content, and a side menu:

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
    <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-view name="maincontent">
        </ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-side-menu side="left"">
        <ion-content>
            <div class="list">
                <!-- static menu items here -->
                <!-- and I want to add menu items here relevant 
                     to the child view-->
            </div>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

I also have a child view:

```
.state("app.questionnaire", {
    url: "/questionnaire/:id",
    views: {
        "maincontent": {
            templateUrl: "app/questionnaire/questionnaire.html",
            controller: "QuestionnaireController as vm"
        }
    }
})
```

I now want to add menu items to the main menu when I am viewing the child view -  but the items are dynamic. In my questionnaire controller I have this line to retrieve the sections and add them to that controllers model:

```
vm.sections = $filter('orderBy')(questionnaire.Sections, 'SortOrder');
```

And I want to add links to each section to the side menu. Is there a neat way to do that? Perhaps using `angular-ui-router` and adding another `ion-nav-view` to the menu?

Comment: I came across this recently, pretty much what you are wanting to do - https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/dynamically-change-side-menu-content/14529/6?u=michaeldoye

Comment: @M.Doye that's useful, but an added complication is that my child items are not static (I've now added that info to the question). So the child needs to inject the html into the parent or the parent needs to retrieve the data from the child. Kind of similar to the way the child itself is injected into the `ion-nav-view` named 'maincontent'

Comment: Have you tried to `$scope.$emit()` your dynamic sections from the child view, then listening to them in the abstract state controller; if you emit the data needed to build menu items appropriately you could try `ng-repeat` on the menu items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did this in the parent controller:

```
function MenuLayoutController() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.reset = function () {
        vm.items = [];
    };

    vm.showMenu = function (questionnaire){
       vm.items = questionnaire.menuItems;
    }

    vm.reset();
}
```

And this in my child controller:

```
function QuestionnaireController($scope, /*etc*/){
   var vm = this;
   vm.menuItems = //fetch menu items

   //use scope to get a handle on the parent view model
   var parentmodel = $scope.$parent.vm;
   parentmodel.showMenu(vm);

    //reset the parent view when this controller is destroyed to remove the menu
    $scope.$on("$destroy", function () {
        parentmodel.reset();
    });
}
```